# Can I transfer a file in an object in formData format?

Tags: reactjs, axios, multipartform-data

The forms provided by BackEnd are as follows

```
{
    dataInputDto: {

        itemIndex: string,
        addAuditData: {
                dataAnswer: string,
                fileList: Array<File>
        }

    }
}
```

I am using React and would like to send the data in multipart/formData format. But I've never transferred a file in that format, so please give me some advice!

Comment: `formData.append("file", file);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope You're doing well.

Let me share you a code snippet for the same so you may refer it and proceed further.

**The Submit function for the formData**

```
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
let formdata = new FormData();
formdata = { ...formdata, img: data.image[0] };
console.log(formdata, formdata.img.name);

let response = await axios.post(
  `${process.env.REACT_APP_BASEURL}/uploadImg`,
  formdata,
  { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } }
);
```

**The return function of the component is as follows to render the form**

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} encType="multipart/form-data">
Id: <br />
<input type="text" {...register("id")} defaultValue={id} readOnly />
<br />
Name: <br />
<input type="text" {...register("name")} required />
 
Image: <br />
<input type="file" {...register("image")} required/>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" required/>
</form>
```

The Above Code Snippet is refering to image but you may also proceed same for transfering the file.

Kindly Accept the Answer if it works for your query. Thanks & Regards.